# using servlets in a struts 2 project

Tags: java, servlets, struts2

I am building an application using struts2. The web.xml file looks like below

```
<filter> 
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
    <filter-class> 
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter 
    </filter-class> 
</filter> 

<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

The application runs fine. Now I have a JSP which needs some input from servlet, So i wrote a servlet and added servlet-mapping in web.xml, but the server cannot find the servlet because of the filter-mapping. 
How to use servlets in struts 2 and what should web.xml look like?

from: http://struts-2.464677.n5.nabble.com/using-servlets-in-a-struts-2-project-td465399.html

Answer (score 1):

That particular servlet should be excluded from you Struts filter in struts.xml