# How to use a servlet in annotations based struts2 project having no struts.xml

Tags: servlets, struts2

I am new to Struts and I have to add a functionality to a legacy system.

I have to create a servlet that's required to be accessed from a JSP page. I created one and added servlet-mapping in the web.xml file but it always shows an error like the following:

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/myServlet] and action name
   [test] associated with context path [/MyProject]
```

I have searched for the solution but the one I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891477/using-servlets-in-a-struts-2-project) is for the sturts.xml entry and I am not using the struts.xml, rather I am using the annotations.

Could someone please tell me how to use `excludePattern` in a annotations based Struts2 project?
NOTE: I tried adding the exclue-pattern in my web.xml like this:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>struts.action.excludePattern</param-name>
  <param-value>/FileUploadServlet</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But it's still not working.

Comment: Just create struts.xml or use properties. Side note: Are you sure you need a servlet?

Comment: Thanks @AleksandrM for the reply. Actually I do need the servlet. I am wondering if I create struts.xml, then will my annotations work as is OR I will have to add mappings in the struts.xml instead of the annotations?

Comment: It will work. Actually you can mix struts.xml defined actions with annotations. Also because `struts.action.excludePattern` takes patterns you can add `.*` to mapping in order to use more than one servlet. See [Jersey with Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17293115/1700321).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have solved the problem by adding struts.xml to my project and adding only the constant there like this:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/MyServlet"/>
```

I was first wondering that I will have to provide all the mappings manually instead of the annotations but it worked without doing so.